# Create Ubuntu ISO identical to Docker Hub image of Ubuntu

Tags: iso, docker, versions

I developed a program working inside a docker container to be independent of my personal devices' libraries. Now I would like to setup a real computer from scratch to use it to run my program (and know that it is the **identical** environment in which I developed).

In my Dockerfile that I used I run:

```
From ubuntu:focal-20220404
```

I see that on Docker Hub [Canonical's rootfs tarballs](https://partner-images.canonical.com/oci/focal/20220404/) are referenced. They also include a `*.manifest` file which (if I understand correctly) describes all installed packages (including which version). But how to proceed with this knowledge?

Following [Ubuntu's installation tutorial](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/installation) I am forwarded to download the [20.04 Ubuntu image](https://releases.ubuntu.com/20.04/) but there is no choice for different versions as are published on [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/ubuntu). Is there a way to achieve what I want?

Thanks a lot in advance!

mammah

Comment: Let me ask you the reverse question: Why are you in doubt your program will run on the latest Ubuntu 20.04 image? The whole point of Ubuntu LTS is that's it's binary compatible, so I don't see any reason why it wouldn't work. However, there are inherent differences between a Docker image and a full system image (for instance Docker image don't have systemd, nor it's own kernel). Did you consider to just test it?

Comment: Thanks for your input @ArturMeinild! The requirement of "identical" setups is purely because of law regulations. I am certain that my program runs on a updated Ubuntu version as well (also tested it). However, my goal was to have a lightweight way to develop the program (within a "frozen" environment) and then to have a final product with the same specs on a proper machine. Do you know resources to get a better overview of the inherent differences of my two environments?